# How to use global variabels in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, global-variables

I have a search form in my homepage with two fields in it and i given action to **page 2** and used session variables in **page 2** code to store the value received using that form via post method to access those Session variables in the **page 4**. This is working only if the user is logged in. So i have another option which is using "**global**". I tried using

```
global $a;
$a = $_SESSION['name'];
```

in functions.php and in the page 2 as well but i'm unable to fetch that value to page 4.

So how can i use global in wordpress. I also tried placing header.php and footer.php but not worked.

Comment: use `$_SESSION` and don't forgot to initialize the session via `session_start()`.

Comment: session_start() is already available.

Comment: `global` did not work in different pages. and you need to use the global in any function for global variable.

Comment: Ok. Can you please show me a example code?

Comment: I don't think so you need global for any `$_SESSION` value cause the `$_SESSION` is available everywhere in the page.

Comment: I can give an example how to use global in any page.

Comment: I used $_SESSION instead of global but not worked for non logged in users.

Comment: @FrayneKonok please give me example code.

Comment: my code is not the solution of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are accessible only in the same request.
if you to share values on different pages and different requests use sessions.

```
//add  this line on top of your theme's functions.php
if( !session_id() ) {
    session_start();
}
```

and assign values like that

```
$_SESSION['PAGE_NUM'] = 'MY_VALUE'
```

Comment: Yes. I did the same thing you mentioned but it only works for logged in user but i need for everyone.

Comment: did you try it using cookies..?

Answer (score -1):

TO fetch the value on page4 first declare the global variable again on that page4 like

```
global $a;
```

Comment: on page4 have u started the session if not than use this at the top of the page session_start();

Comment: Yes, i have started session in page 4 also...its only working if user is logged in.

Comment: use session_start() before the user logged in check on what ever page you have created that

Answer (score -1):

Use of WordPress Global Variables

**we can use it in function.php**

```
function sample() {
 global $a;
 $a = 'hello world';
 }
 add_action( 'after_theme_setup', 'sample' );
```

**Retrieving global data**

```
<?php
  global $a;   
  print_r( $a ); ?>
```

Next, let's edit the page.php

```
 <div id="primary" class="content-area">
<div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

    <?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

        global $a; 
        print_r( $a );

        // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.

        if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
            comments_template();
        }

    endwhile;
    ?>

</div><!-- #content -->
```